# PostgreSQL: How to show personal bests by comparing to previous runs

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I'm looking to create the "fastest_run_time" column in PostgreSQL by looking at what the "current" personal best is as of the month of that row. So for example:

[image]

- In 2016-07 my personal best was 762, it was beaten by a 720 in 2016-08
- Since the run on 2016-09 of 745 isn't an improvement on 720, the fastest_run_time should stay as 720
- It's only updated again when it is beaten with a 691 in 2016-12.

I've tried doing some partitioning and max/mins and have got it into this format but can't really see where to go from here

[image]

Comment: Erm. And what's the question?

Comment: The "fastest_run_time" column is currently just hardcoded by me to show what i'm trying to get calculated within SQL, the first 3 columns are part of a table. How can I create the fastest_run_time column to get the values to look like they are in those pictures?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the partition by syntax is supported:

```
select mt.*,
min(run_time) over 
        (partition by run_type 
         order by period 
         rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as fastest_run_time 
from mytbl mt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a subquery:

```sql
select run_type, to_char(period, 'YYYY-MM'), run_time, (
    select min(rs.run_time) from run rs
        where rs.period <= run.period
) fastest_run_time from run;
```

[Demo with schema](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pVLedUmrGJLihHicvzS4Gf/0).

Result:

| run_type | to_char | run_time | fastest_run_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2021-05 |  |  |
| A | 2021-06 | 762 | 762 |
| A | 2021-07 | 762 | 762 |
| A | 2021-08 | 720 | 720 |
| A | 2021-09 | 745 | 720 |
| A | 2021-10 | 745 | 720 |
| A | 2021-11 | 745 | 720 |
| A | 2021-12 | 691 | 691 |

---